# Bevel modifier for 2-material-object

Tags: bevel

I'm having an issue when I apply *Bevel* modifier for an object having 2 materials.

The corners pieces seem always take the wrong material. I cannot set it right with the Material index other then -1m since the other bevels will get the wrong color.

I can isolate the edges adding the extra loops, but I don't want to make the geometry more complicated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you want the bevel parts be all the same material, but the other one? or?

Comment: @lemon I would like the corner small black pieces of the bevel to be white.